# How to use recursion in MYSQL View

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have a table called `categories`. In it, there are three columns: `id`, `parentId`, and `name`. The `parentId` column is a foreign key that references the `id` column of the same table.

**categories**

```
| id | parentId | name      |
|----|----------|-----------|
|  1 |   NULL   | expense   |
|  2 |        1 | food      |
|  3 |        2 | grocery   |
|  4 |        3 | meat      |
|  5 |        3 | fruit     |
|  6 |        2 | dining    |
```

I want to create a view called `categories_view` which returns the `categories` table and adds a column called `path` which creates a path for that record which is the path of the parent (if the parent is not `NULL`) and the name of the `name`.

**categories_view**

```
| id | parentId | name      | path                             |
|----|----------|-----------|----------------------------------|
|  1 |   NULL   | expense   | expense                          |
|  2 |        1 | food      | expense > food                   |
|  3 |        2 | grocery   | expense > food > grocery         |
|  4 |        3 | meat      | expense > food > grocery > meat  |
|  5 |        3 | fruit     | expense > food > grocery > fruit |
|  6 |        2 | dining    | expense > food > dining          |
```

If I were doing this with javascript or something, I could just use recursion, but I'm not sure how to do that in SQL views.

Comment: What does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth - it shows 8.0.26

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a recursive CTE inside a view:

```sql
CREATE VIEW categories_view AS
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT id, parentId, name, name AS path
    FROM categories
    WHERE parentId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c.id, c.parentId, c.name, CONCAT_WS(' > ', t.path, c.name)
    FROM categories c
    INNER JOIN cte t ON c.parentId = t.id
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=f280a4382dc514abe0e0465babd8c48b) showing that the logic is working.